# Trying to have title and dates in google sheets automatically sync up with a Google calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I managed to get something working where it will take the title and date and put it in the Google calendar but I have to run the script every time. But when I alter a date for an event (dates are always changing) it just makes another event and keeps the old one.

I just want to have a google sheet with titles and dates for when things are happening to be synced up to a google calendar and when dates change, it modifies one event without making new ones. Ideally, without having to run the script every time as well.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = "test calendar";
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var schedule = spreadsheet.getRange("A4:B6").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<schedule.length; x++) {
    var shifts = schedule[x];
    var Eventnames = shifts[0];
    var DateofEvent = shifts[1];

    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Eventnames, DateofEvent);
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about `I just want to have a google sheet with titles and dates for when things are happening to be synced up to a google calendar and when dates change, it modifies one event without making new ones. Ideally, without having to run the script every time as well.`. I apologize for this. Do you want a Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to accomplish this

1. Create a column for Calendar_Event_ID (column C in this example)
2. Run this code to create calendar events for all of your events (same as your code with modification to save calendar event id in Calendar_Event_ID column). You will end up with a data structure as follows:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EventName1 | EventDate1 | EventId1 |
| EventName2 | EventDate2 | EventId2 |

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarEventIdColumn = 3 // put the number of your column choice here (C = 3)
  var dataStartRow = 4 // you started at A4 in your example, so I am starting with row 4
  var calendarEventIds = []; // this will store a list of calendar event IDs
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = "test calendar";
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var schedule = spreadsheet.getRange("A4:C6").getValues(); // added column C to include the calendar event ids

  for (var x=0; x < schedule.length; x++) {
    var shifts = schedule[x];
    var Eventnames = shifts[0];
    var DateofEvent = shifts[1];
    var eventId = shifts[2];
    var event;
    // if the event already exists, edit it. Otherwise create a new one.
    if (eventId !== '') {
      event = eventCal.getEventById(eventId);
      event.setTitle(Eventnames);
      event.setAllDayDate(DateofEvent);
    } else {
      event = eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Eventnames, DateofEvent);  
    }
    calendarEventIds.push([event.getId()]); // add the event id to list of event ids 
  }
  // save the new calendar event IDs under the calendarEventIdColumn
  spreadsheet.getRange(dataStartRow, calendarEventIdColumn, calendarEventIds.length, 1).setValues(calendarEventIds);
}
```

3. Re-run `myFunction` every time you edit an event's date or name. Note that you can do this 'manually' by running the function in the apps script code editor, by creating a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), or with an [edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: Nice answer, to OP, you can also use [`createEvent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime) instead of `createAllDayEvent` but that would require one more column (one for start time and one for end time) , though if you want all day events, then this script works well.